# Best way to get, manipulate & write (response) huge JSON in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My expected task : Get huge data (1 GB & More in size) json string , manipulate (do some formatting,parsing json, restructuring the json data )  and write the new formatted json string as response.
What is the better way to handle this scenario ?

From some blog I found storing huge data in stream is efficient way to handle huge amount of data, but How to I manipulate stream data ?

Exception/ Error that I face : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)

Input JSON :

`"docs": [
      {
        "note_text": ["7657011|20MAR08|somehugedata|||7657012|20MAR09|somehugedata"],
        id:"c123"
      },
      {
        "note_text": ["7657001|23MAR08|somehugedata|||7657002|21MAR08|somehugedata"],
        id:"c124"
      }
]`

new formatted JSON:

`"docs": [
      {
        id:"c123",
        note_text : "somehugedata",
        date : "20MAR08"
        note_id : "7657011"
      },
      {
        id:"c123",
        note_text : "somehugedata",
        date : "20MAR09"
        note_id : "7657012"
      },
      {
        id:"c124",
        note_text : "somehugedata",
        date : "23MAR08"
        note_id : "7657001"
      },
      {
        id:"c124",
        note_text : "somehugedata",
        date : "21MAR08"
        note_id : "7657002"
      }
]`

Comment: link to blog. "efficient" could mean lots of things and may be inappropriate for your purposes

Comment: I missed the one which I got, but this one is much similar to that - [nodejs-jsonstringify-a-1gb-object-running-out-of-memory](http://www.xiandg.com/2671412/codep1/nodejs-jsonstringify-a-1gb-object-running-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream). With it you don't have to load the whole huge JSON blob into memory. You'll process objects in the source JSON one by one, specifying the proper selection pattern for them in the `JSONStream.parse()`.